# How to convert JSON string to an array

Tags: c#, json, ssis, json-deserialization

I have the following JSON string:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Test diagnosis",
      "code":"324324",
      "table":"EXAMPLE",
      "addedby":"EDnurse",
      "dateadded":3243243,
      "qualifier":[
         {
            "name":"Qualifier",
            "value":"Confirmed Diagnosis",
            "code":"23434434",
            "prefix":"[C] "
         },
         {
            "name":"Left/Right",
            "value":"Bilateral",
            "code":"324343",
            "suffix":" - Bilateral"
         }
      ],
      "prefix":"[C] ",
      "suffix":" - Bilateral"
   }
]
```

You can see that the Qualifier field in this JSON String is nested and has 2 objects.

I am working on a package that parses this JSON string using C# in SSIS. I can Parse the string with one object of qualifier, but when I add the second object (left/right), and attempt to turn the string into an array, I receive an error.

Without array (works with one Qualifier object):

```
Diagnosis diagnosis = js.Deserialize<Diagnosis>(reviewConverted);
```

With array (returns error stating that I cannot implicitly convert type diagnosis to type diagnosis ):

```
Diagnosis diagnosis = js.Deserialize<List<Diagnosis>>(reviewConverted);
```

I also use the following Class to define my diagnosis fields:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SC_8aae662509ae4bab8491323924579173
{
    class Diagnosis
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string table { get; set; }
        public string addedby { get; set; }
        public string dateadded { get; set; }

        public qualifier Qualifier { get; set; }

        public string prefix { get; set; }
        public string suffix { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Here is my qualifier class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SC_8aae662509ae4bab8491323924579173
{
    class qualifier
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string prefix { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't your qualifier property in your Diagnosis class be a List<Qualifier> ?

Comment: can you post the `Qualifier` class code as well?

Comment: because it might fail as well due to different properties in the two array objects where in the first it is called `prefix` and in the second it is called `suffix` and it will not be able to automatically deserialize  it.

Comment: Added the qualifier class - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can tell, based on what you're saying, 1 Diagnosis object, can contain multiple Qualifier objects. So what you need to do is the following:
First, change your Diagnosis class to have the following property:

```
public qualifier List<Qualifier> { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public qualifier Qualifier { get; set; }
```

Also the following statement is what gives you an error:

```
Diagnosis diagnosis = js.Deserialize<List<Diagnosis>>(reviewConverted);
```

You are trying to store in a Diagnosis objext a List of Diagnosis object, which makes no sense of course.

Comment: Thank you - this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like below?

```
class Diagnosis
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string table { get; set; }
    public string addedby { get; set; }
    public string dateadded { get; set; }

    public List<Qualifier> qualifier { get; set; }

    public string prefix { get; set; }
    public string suffix { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - it helped me towards the solution above.